# How to get jQuery style navigation bar without using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a mobile website, but on a few of the pages, I can't use jQuery, so is there a way I can have the same navigation bars as i do on the jQuery pages? (I don't need the effects.)

This is what I'm using for a navigation bar in jquery:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
<a href="a_certain_page.html" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<a href="index.html"  data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS3.  May I ask why you can't use jQuery?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery on only a few pages?

Comment: I cant use jquery because I have link 50 anchors on the page and jquery doesn't support anchors, and Its just a simple website with jquery style buttons and navigation bar.... all i want on the page that cant use jquery is the nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he he.. i just copyed the css to do that. so just use the element inspector and copy the style.

```
/** header barr */
div.header
{
    padding: 5px 5ex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,#81a8ce,#5e87b0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#81a8ce,#5e87b0);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#81a8ce,#5e87b0);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#81a8ce,#5e87b0);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#81a8ce,#5e87b0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
div.header h1
{
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #254F7A;
    color:white;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}
```

its not exact. but a nice aproximation i thout.

Comment: Can you put the CSS in your answer? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring this out do you think you could put it in a jfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ Thanks, I apologize I'm a total beginner so I have a hard time understanding stuff :)